# How to reopen existing indexedDB database on another page

Tags: indexeddb, indexeddbshim

I have created indexedDB database that contain multiple table and data. now i want to reopen existing indexedDB database and want to read data from specific tables.please help me

Answer (score 3):

## IDB version number

In IndexedDB, typically database is opened (opened for the first time or re-opened for modification) using `window.indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);`

Here, `DB_VERSION` is the version number of database that determines whether database will be opened for creation or modification or read.

Further readings:

- [Mozilla IDB guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Updating_the_version_of_the_database)
- [W3C IDB specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)

## How IDB version number works

- For the **first time** when you call `open`, you will typically call with version number as 1, which will fire `onupgradeneeded` event handler (this event handler can be used to "create" database schema) and `onsuccess` event handler (this event handler will be used to save database handler) in order, and then you can access the database using the database handler.
- Next time when you may call `open` with **a upgraded/higher version number** then again `onupgradeneeded` event handler (this event handler can be used to "create" database schema) and `onsuccess` event handler (this event handler will be used to save database handler) will be fired in order.
- Next time when you may call `open` with **same version number (reopen for read)** then again only `onsuccess` event handler (this event handler will be used to save database handler) will be fired in order.

### Please note

- `onupgradeneeded` event handler is used to create or modify database schema.
- `onsuccess` event handler is used to get the database handler which will be used to access database.
- **IMPORTANT:** Typically you should not call `open` again and again (*until you wish to modify the database schema*), but for the first time when you call then you should save the database handler using `onsuccess` event handler and then access the database using that database handler.

### Example code for understanding

Use below once, and see the alerts, then execute again (*without clear cache on browser so that same database still exists*) and then see the alert.

```
    var request = window.indexedDB.open("SO", 1);

    request.onblocked = function(event) {
        alert("Error, cannot open database. Error message: Database in blocked state. " +
                "Please close all open windows, clear browser cache and use a fresh window.");
    };

    //Callback for error upon DB open 
    request.onerror = function(event) {
      alert('Error, cannot open database/Erreur, ne peut pas ouvrir la base de donn&#233;es');
    };

    //Callback for success upon DB open
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        alert('onsuccess. Save your database handler, for example something, DB_HANDLER = event.target.result;');
    };

    //Callback for onupgradeneeded upon DB open
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        alert('onupgradeneeded. Create/modify the database schema');
    };
```

Comment: So, does it answer your question or have any other question ??